# Como checar se meu registro de uma coluna (FK) está presente em outras tabelas?

Tags: sql, oracle

Quero deletar um registro, porém as vezes o oracle reclama:

**Erro de SQL: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (SGR20_HOMOLOG.TB_CONFIGURACAO_EXERCICIO_T436) violated - child record found
02292. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - child record found"**

Gostaria então de utilizar uma query que checasse se há dependências desse registro, para que em seguida eu fosse ou não para a query de delete.

Existe alguma forma de obter essa resposta através de uma query? Como ficaria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto que você deseja fazer é interessante porém teria mais custo ao banco de dados do que você tentar apagar o registro direto. Vou te demostrar porque.

Primeiro você tem que se basear neste select:

```
SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c.owner, 
       c.r_owner, c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
  FROM all_cons_columns a
  JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                        AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
  JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                           AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
 WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R'
   AND a.table_name = :tabela
```

Depois você tem que pegar cada tabela e os referidos campos e fazer um select para ver se tem o dados. Imagine uma tabela grande com alguns milhões de registro. Olha quanto isto pode demorar!!!

Por isto é mais fácil você fazer as FK com um padrão e tratar isto dentro do sistema. 
Eu uso o padrão:

TABELA_PK
TABELA_FKXX

Pois assim sei o nome da tabela com problema e vou procurar o indice XX para ver qual a referencia e qual o problema que está existindo.

Espero ter ajudado.